# How to open a URL with corresponding data of clicked Edge of a Bokeh graph

Tags: python, bokeh

I'm trying to open an URL with parameters corresponding to an **edge** of a networkx graph rendered with Bokeh. I was able to use the HoverTool with a tooltip to load an image matching the URL that I need, the URL being a template filled with the parameters from the Edge data of my graph ('color' and 'weight'). Here is a simplified example:

```
import networkx as nx

from bokeh.io import show, output_file
from bokeh.models import Plot, Range1d, MultiLine, Circle, TapTool, OpenURL, HoverTool
from bokeh.models.graphs import from_networkx, EdgesAndLinkedNodes
from bokeh.palettes import Spectral4

tooltips = """
<div id="picture" style="width : 550px; position: fixed; left: 250px; top: 80px">
    <div>
        <img
            src="http://localhost/@color/@weight/" alt="http://localhost/@color/@weight/" height=300
            border="2"
        ></img>
    </div>
</div>
"""

G = nx.Graph()
G.add_node('X', color='color of node')
G.add_edge('Y', 'X', weight=6, color="blue")
G.add_edge('Z', 'X', weight=3, color="yellow")
G.add_edge('Y', 'Z', weight=7, color="red")

plot = Plot(plot_width=800, plot_height=800,
            x_range=Range1d(-1.1,1.1), y_range=Range1d(-1.1,1.1))

graph_renderer = from_networkx(G, nx.circular_layout, scale=1, center=(0,0))
graph_renderer.node_renderer.glyph = Circle(size=15, fill_color=Spectral4[0])
graph_renderer.node_renderer.selection_glyph = Circle(size=15, fill_color=Spectral4[2])
graph_renderer.node_renderer.hover_glyph = Circle(size=15, fill_color=Spectral4[1])
graph_renderer.edge_renderer.glyph = MultiLine(line_color="#CCCCCC", line_alpha=0.8, line_width=5)
graph_renderer.edge_renderer.selection_glyph = MultiLine(line_color=Spectral4[2], line_width=5)
graph_renderer.edge_renderer.hover_glyph = MultiLine(line_color=Spectral4[1], line_width=5)
graph_renderer.selection_policy = EdgesAndLinkedNodes()
graph_renderer.inspection_policy = EdgesAndLinkedNodes()

plot.renderers.append(graph_renderer)

url = "http://localhost/@color/@weight/@index"
plot.add_tools(HoverTool(tooltips=tooltips), TapTool(callback=OpenURL(url=url)))

output_file("example.html")

show(plot)
```

For instance, hovering an edge, the image that is loaded in the tooltip is:

http://localhost/blue/6

Now my goal is to open this URL in a new tab when clicking an edge. I'm using a TapTool with the OpenURL callback. This time, the url template is populated with the information from the closest **node** and not from the edge. For instance, it tries to open:

http://localhost/color%20of%20node/???/X

Is there a way to use OpenURL the way I intend it to work?

I'm guessing an option for me is to create a custom JS callback in TapTool instead of using OpenURL. I was able to get my x and y position of the clicked glyph, but I don't know how to retrieve the data information from the clicked edge to build a URL with the 'color' and 'weight' data. Any ideas how to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass your url to JS callback and open it using `open()` method like in example below. Clicking on a node will print the callback object `cb_obj`, callback data `cb_data` and other info to the Developers Tools console e.g. in Google Chrome. Also the selected indexes and corresponding data values will be printed. Note that your `graph_renderer.selection_policy` will be applied first before executing this the JS callback. I hope it helps

```
import networkx as nx

from bokeh.io import show, output_file
from bokeh.models import Plot, Range1d, MultiLine, Circle, TapTool, OpenURL, HoverTool, CustomJS
from bokeh.models.graphs import from_networkx, EdgesAndLinkedNodes
from bokeh.palettes import Spectral4

tooltips = """
<div id="picture" style="width : 550px; position: fixed; left: 250px; top: 80px">
    <div>
        <img
            src="http://localhost/@color/@weight/" alt="http://localhost/@color/@weight/" height=300
            border="2"
        ></img>
    </div>
</div> """

G = nx.Graph()
G.add_node('X', color = 'color of node')
G.add_edge('Y', 'X', weight = 6, color = "blue")
G.add_edge('Z', 'X', weight = 3, color = "yellow")
G.add_edge('Y', 'Z', weight = 7, color = "red")

plot = Plot(x_range = Range1d(-1.1, 1.1), y_range = Range1d(-1.1, 1.1))

graph_renderer = from_networkx(G, nx.circular_layout, scale = 1, center = (0, 0))
graph_renderer.node_renderer.glyph = Circle(size = 15, fill_color = Spectral4[0])
graph_renderer.node_renderer.selection_glyph = Circle(size = 15, fill_color = Spectral4[2])
graph_renderer.node_renderer.hover_glyph = Circle(size = 15, fill_color = Spectral4[1])
graph_renderer.edge_renderer.glyph = MultiLine(line_color = "#CCCCCC", line_alpha = 0.8, line_width = 5)
graph_renderer.edge_renderer.selection_glyph = MultiLine(line_color = Spectral4[2], line_width = 5)
graph_renderer.edge_renderer.hover_glyph = MultiLine(line_color = Spectral4[1], line_width = 5)
graph_renderer.selection_policy = EdgesAndLinkedNodes()
graph_renderer.inspection_policy = EdgesAndLinkedNodes()

plot.renderers.append(graph_renderer)

url = "http://localhost/@color/@weight/@index"
code = ''' 
//open(url);
console.log(cb_obj); 
console.log(cb_data); 
console.log(cb_data.source.selected.indices);
console.log(cb_data.source.data);
selected = cb_data.source.selected.indices
if (selected.length > 0)
    for (index in selected)
        console.log('index: ' + selected[index] + ', value: ' + cb_data.source.data.index[selected[index]])
console.log(''); '''
callback_tap_tool = CustomJS(args = dict(url = url), code = code)
plot.add_tools(HoverTool(tooltips = tooltips), TapTool(callback = callback_tap_tool))

output_file("example.html")

show(plot)
```